# Could not find artifact com.test:1.1.3 in repository.jboss.org-public

Tags: java, spring, sonar-runner

I'm having an issue in Spring Project which i'm trying to use `mvn sonar:sonar`, but it's not working it's displaying this error:

```
Could not find artifact com.test:1.1.3 in repository.jboss.org-public (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public) and
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 10
```

But i have already installed the dependency:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>jenkinspom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </parent>
```

What's could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Youre artifact has the name `com.test.jenkinsPom`.

But you error message says just prints out the groupId `com.test` and the version.